# Looking for code files

Tags: cycles-render-engine, documentation, source-code

I'm working on a project that will be evaluated in my university class "image processing and computer vision":
I'm trying to recreate some experiment we studied in class with Cycles and, in order to do so, i need to access the "sample patter" code: the "correlated multi-jitter" should be the most usefull patter to work on but i can't find the code anywhere.
I already checked the documentation and the wiki and asked on a bunch of groups and pages, but nobody seems capable to help.

Thank to all those who'll answer.
Have a nice day

Comment: "I need to access the sample pattern code", " I already checked....". Did you download the source code and search among the files? [Blender · rB](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the correlated multi-jitter can be found in [`blender/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_jitter.h`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/bc6bbe5fac864ded3a00f4a50d5eb79f89b74c75/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_jitter.h#L137) . The functions are called `cmj_sample_1D` and `cmj_sample_2D`. The code is based on [*Andrew Kensler, "Correlated Multi-Jittered Sampling"*, Pixar Technical Memo 13-01, 2013.](http://graphics.pixar.com/library/MultiJitteredSampling/paper.pdf)

Here is how you can find this yourself:

1. Enabled *Python Tooltips* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Interface*)
2. Hover over the sampling pattern drop-down in the UI until the tooltip appears. Take note of properties name, it is `sampling_pattern`.
3. Search for `sampling_pattern` in Blender's code. This can either be done in your local copy of the code or online through [Blender's website](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/?grep=sampling_pattern) or its [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/blender/blender/search?q=sampling_pattern&unscoped_q=sampling_pattern).
4. Find the code that implements the property first and try to figure out how it is used. You will notice that the property can be found in [`blender/intern/cycles/blender/addon/properties.py`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/c3651adf8914048ecd2668937c3ed4414a6707bd/intern/cycles/blender/addon/properties.py#L320) and the values that can be select for it come from `enum_sampling_pattern`.
5. The type that defines the enums that could be assigned can be seen in [`blender/intern/cycles/render/integrator.cpp`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/3033b2a0442fad0af9a2f57054397fec4efba97b/intern/cycles/blender/blender_sync.cpp#L284) and [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/2d1cce8331f3ecdfb8cb0c651e111ffac5dc7153/intern/cycles/render/integrator.cpp#L85). The name of the enum is [`SamplingPattern`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/5801a016d4cf2384274b0f813e29d61662dc8ee2/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_types.h#L270). The entry `SAMPLING_PATTERN_CMJ` is for the correlated multi-jitter.
6. [Searching for the occurrences of `SAMPLING_PATTERN_CMJ`](https://github.com/blender/blender/search?q=SAMPLING_PATTERN_CMJ&unscoped_q=SAMPLING_PATTERN_CMJ) shows that it is used in [`blender/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_random.h`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/d195deef5cbfe2951dceb2a11959091fbd263440/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_random.h#L64). The functions to compute the correlated multi-jitter are called `cmj_sample_1D` and `cmj_sample_2D`. Both are implemented in [`blender/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_jitter.h`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/bc6bbe5fac864ded3a00f4a50d5eb79f89b74c75/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_jitter.h#L137) .

Comment: Thanks for the hunting-down instructions.. very useful. Q: Why are these function definitions in header files?

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm not sure, I'd have to ask the other devs. I *think* it might be, because it allows to use the code for CUDA and OpenCL.

Comment: This is really helpfull, thank you a lot.
Hope to show you some good result soon!
Have a nice day ;)

Comment: @LeonardoVezzani If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.